# Set up Kiosk in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, system-installation, printing, scanner, startup-applications

I received call one of a company. They are implementing and installing Ubuntu Desktop OS in there client systems and they need:

> Create one user as a temporary user and that user should have 3 options enabled in client system:
>
> 1. google chrome with one fixed URL(http:192.168.1.1)
> 2. printer access for printing
> 3. scanner access for upload docs.
>
> All remaining functionality should be disabled.

For the above process, what resources do we have to use and how can we disable everything? The Company is asking to make a professional document for the above installation. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I am afraid we have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: hi Jacob i need how to block all applications except google crome or any other browsers

Comment: I see. You might want to edit the wuestion a bit :)

Comment: ok i will tell you clearly  i will install ubuntu os in one system ok i will create one user call as a temp ok when the user login automatic any one browser should be open all other icons and applications should be block. user open browser and do his work.  i need to block everything except browser

Comment: I don't mean adding it in a comment, but editing the question. The downvote wasn't mine btw.

Comment: ok can you help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

Question seems to be related to creating a Kiosk Mode Ubuntu session. If this is the case, you have several options.

- **Ubuntu**: you have two options here. First, you can just install a light version of Ubuntu and customize it such as it becomes a kiosk. Or you can start from a full ubuntu desktop and customize it to become a kiosk. Naturally, the former is better in terms of resource use. There are plenty of guides online, so it would be a bit redundant to write all the steps here. [This](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/create-ubuntu-kiosk) guide is an example (for 14.04, but it should work for 16.04 too).
- **Purpose built kiosk OS**: there are a several options around of open-source OS that are basically just a Kiosk mode. As such, they are very light in resources requirements. A few examples: [Porteus Kiosk](http://porteus-kiosk.org), [Symphony OS](http://www.symphonyos.com/kiosk-mode) and [Instant WebKiosk](http://www.binaryemotions.com/web-kiosks/webkiosk-os/).

Comment: It would be preferable if you could include the main points of those external links into your question. Link-only answers are not appreciated as links may become obsolete which would render the answer useless.